# ¿Por que me da esta excepción? Exception: TypeError: Illegal invocation at HTMLCollection.remoteFunction

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

```
var celdas = document.getElementsByClassName("celda");
alert(celdas.length);
```

Aqui el resultado del length de celda da cero 0, pero si que regresa las celdas.

Comment: Acabo de correrlo en mi entrono local y funciona (muestra el número de div con clase celda que he creado), exactamente que es lo que no te funciona?

Comment: gracias por tu ayuda!. ya encontré la solución.